# .Net based open source search engine?

Tags: c#, .net, search, visual-studio-2008, search-engine

I am looking for an easy to use, maintain and extensible search engine (intranet, enterprise search engine) based on .Net technologies, better open source which is more capable of extension. Just similar to Apache Lucene and Apache Solr. I want to search html page only.

I tried Microsoft Search Server and find it is not easy to maintain, use and extend, not easy to make own UI, bound too tight to SharePoint. I am using VSTS 2008 + C#.

Comment: Was there a problem with Lucene.NET? http://incubator.apache.org/lucene.net/

Comment: Hi mxmissile, please correct me if I am wrong. 1. Seems Lucene.Net does not have a web crawler which crawls page regularly. It is just a search tool? 2. I want to find a ready to use product, and seems Lucene.Net is just an SDK? Not a web based search engine like Bing/Google?

Comment: Hi Jon, how good is Lucene.Net for non en-us language? I download a copy of Lucene.Net and find it uses common code to index for all language files. Any experience of index/search for non en-us language, like France, Japanese? Any plug-in needed for such language?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Lucene.Net](http://incubator.apache.org/lucene.net/)?

Comment: I have never used it. I want to find a ready to use product, and seems it is just an SDK? Not a web based search engine like Bing/Google?

Comment: Seems Lucene.Net does not have a web crawler which crawls page regularly. It is just a search tool?

Comment: You asked for something "similar to Apache Lucene" - in what way is Lucene.Net *not* similar to Lucene?

Comment: I don't believe Solr includes a crawler either, by the way...

Comment: Sorry Jon, my bad description. I want to have a full featured search engine, like Microsoft Search Server, Google and Bing. Any suggestions for any .Net open source project of such type?

Comment: I don't know of any full crawler + engine + UI, no.

Comment: Hi Jon, how good is Lucene.Net for non en-us language? I download a copy of Lucene.Net and find it uses common code to index for all language files. Any experience of index/search for non en-us language, like France, Japanese? Any plug-in needed for such language?

Comment: @George2: I don't know - I've never used Lucene myself, in either form.

Comment: Thanks for all of your help, Jon. I have marked your reply as answered.

Answer (score 5):

[arachnode.net](http://arachnode.net/) it's a web crawler + Lucent.Net

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for an out of the box, configurable, free solution, you can check out [Searchblox](http://www.searchblox.com), I have had pretty good success with it.  It's not open source though.